# Removing a route from Auth::routes()

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.3

I have these routes:

```
Auth::routes();
Route::get('/home', 'LibraryController@home');
Route::get('/', 'LibraryController@index');
```

`Auth::routes()` is generated by the command `php artisan make::auth`. But, i don't want the index page to be under auth middleware group, the third route in the above list.

Here is the controller methods. `index()` is for everyone and `home()` for authenticated users.

```
 public function index()
    {
        return view('index');
    }

    public function home()
    {
        return view('home')->with('message','Logged in!');
    }
```

the login users is redirected to home url:

```
protected $redirectTo = '/home';
```

But whenever i run the third route the login page appears. so, how can i remove that route from auth middleware group.

Comment: please a little explain your question its not clear what you are asking about

Comment: you want to go to direct to home instead of index page??

Comment: @recoverymen no. i don't want `Route::get('/', 'LibraryController@index'); ` route to be under auth middleware.

Comment: you want that LibraryController@index here index method should not be authenticated mean every one can access ? is that your question ?

Comment: i don't see any routes under auth middleware unless you are calling auth middleware method from library controller constructor. if so, remove that method.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your **LibraryController** before index where your controllers start you need to write

```
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth', ['except' => ['index']]);
    }
```

Now every user will be able to go to index method without authentication

Documentation Reference  https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/controllers#controller-middleware

Answer (score 0):

Since Laravel 7.7 you can use `excluded_middleware` property eg:

```php
Route::group([
  'excluded_middleware' => ['auth'],
], function () {
  Route::get('/home', 'LibraryController@home');
  Route::get('/', 'LibraryController@index');   
});
```